# Weird IO behavior with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I am noticing this weird behavior in python- I am trying to record an output from a process, and then read this output and do some processing on it. Even though the file has all the text when I open it after the program runs, I fail to read anything.

Its as simple as

```
f=open("blah.txt",'w')
#I log the output of a program with subprocess
Cmdline="program.exe"
Dump= subprocess.Popen(CmdLine,stdout=f,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
#Waiting for it to finish
while(Dump.poll() is not None): #returns None while subprocess is running
        print "waiting on process to finish \n"
f.flush() #I flush everything to make sure it was written
sys.stdout.flush()
f.close()
#now i need to read from this file

f= open("blah.txt", 'r')
line=f.readline()
while line:
    print line
    line=f.readline()

f.close()
```

I read absolutely nothing, but when I open the file blah.txt after running the program, everything is there. Any hints on what I might be doing wrong? I do not get any prints at all from the "waiting on process to finish" but the process takes about a second to run.

Comment: What is `f`? Shouldn't it be `f = open(...`?

Comment: Sorry, typo.  Fixed. This is not the problem in my program.

Comment: @Illusionist There are quire a number of places where it's obvious that this is not the program you're running. Please post an [*actual* program](http://sscce.org/) with as little modification as possible - otherwise, the error may be somewhere else. For example, [this demo program](https://gist.github.com/phihag/5242061) works fine on my system.

Comment: Minimize your app but make sure that it still reproduces the problem. Post it.

Comment: You almost never want to loop around `poll` like that. If you want to block until it's done, just call `wait`. If you really must busy-wait for some reason, at least `sleep` each time through the loop instead of trying to burn as much CPU time as you can get to do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your code is this part

`while(Dump.poll() is not None): # While dump.pool is not None keep the loop going`

It should be

`while(Dump.poll() is None): # While dump.pool is None keep the loop going`

In your while loop you are essentially keeping the loop going as long as `Dump.poll()` is anything but None. The problem is that `Dump.pool()` is returning None until the process has completed. Which means that the while loop will be cancelled straight away, before you can catch any of the output from the process.

This is an updated version of your code that I confirmed is working as intended.

```
with open("blah.txt",'w') as w:
    #I log the output of a program with subprocess
    Cmdline="program.exe"
    Dump = subprocess.Popen(CmdLine,stdout=w,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    #Waiting for it to finish
    while(Dump.poll() is None): #returns None while subprocess is running
        print "waiting on process to finish \n"
    w.flush() #I flush everything to make sure it was written
    sys.stdout.flush()

#now i need to read from this file
with open("blah.txt", 'r') as f:
    line=f.readline()
    while line:
        print line
        line=f.readline()
```

I would also recommend that you use the [with](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) keyword to make sure that the file is always properly closed after completing it's task.

Comment: a [with](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) -statement automatically closes your file after the suite is done, so `w.close()` and `f.close()` are not necessary

Comment: @ferkulat Ah, forgot to edit that out when pasting his code. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Wait until your Dump process completes:

```
Dump= subprocess.Popen(CmdLine,stdout=f,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
#Waiting for it to finish
Dump.wait() # or -> while(Dump.poll() is None): print...
```

what happens is, since your wait loop is wrong, you don't give the process a change to start before polling so it does not wait it to even start before closing/opening the file:

Comment: +1 Good one, but unless I misunderstood him he mentioned that the file did contain all the expected text, it just didn't show up in the second part.

Comment: yes but it gets populated after the execution of the read-open bit

Comment: btw the problem with his code otherwise is a typo. The while loop should be `is None`, not `is not None`.